# Does the compiler optimize away if statements inside loop

Tags: c#, loops, if-statement, optimization

I'm going through another programmers code and see the following function (and several variations, are called inside a massive loop and in the critical path) and I'm wondering if the c# compiler is smart enough to optimize it:

```
public double SomeFunction(double p_lower, double p_upper) {
   double result = 0.0;
   int low = (int)Math.Ceiling(p_lower);
   int high = (int)Math.Ceiling(p_upper);

   for( int i = low; i <= high; ++i){
      double dbl_low;
      double dbl_high;
      
      if (i == low && i == high) {
        dbl_low = p_lower; // corrected from low in original post
        dbl_high = p_upper; // corrected from high original post
      } else if (i == low) {
        dbl_low = p_lower;
        dbl_high = i;
      } else if (i == high) {
        dbl_low = i - 1;
        dbl_high = p_upper;
      } else {
        dbl_low = i - 1;
        dbl_high = i;
      }
    
      if (dbl_low != dbl_high) {
        result += f(dbl_low,dbl_high);
      }
   }
   return result;
}
```

What this function does is clear, the range from p_lower to p_upper is split up three parts:
Fraction up to the first integer, steps of 1 until the last integer, fraction from last integer to p_upper and call a function on those intervals.

The first condition is the edge case where the both lower and upper are within the same unit interval (correction from original)

My instinct (from when I learned to program and compilers were horrible) would be to rewrite the code as this:

```
public double SomeFunction2(double p_lower, double p_upper) {

   if(p_upper < p_lower){
      return 0.0;
   }

   double result = 0.0;
   double low = Math.Ceiling(p_lower);
   double high = Math.Ceiling(p_upper);
   
   /// edge case
   if (Math.Abs(low - high) < 0.00001) {
     return Math.Abs(p_upper-p_lower)< 0.00001? 0.0 : f(p_lower, p_upper);
   }
   /// first fraction
   result += Math.Abs(low - p_lower)< 0.00001? 0.0 : f(p_lower, low);
   /// whole intervals
   for( double i = low + 1.0; i < high; ++i){ // < instead of <=
     result += f(i-1.0, i);
   }
   /// add last fraction and return
   return result + f(high - 1.0, p_upper);
}
```

This way, there is not a whole cascade of conditional statements that is evaluated every loop, the first of which will always be false after the first, the second will always be true except for the final one. In fact there is no conditional in the loop, since the last condition has been incorporated in the loop range.

The loop counter is a double which should not be an issue since the range for low and high is 0.0 ... 120.0 all of which are exact as a double.

Am I wasting my time and does the compiler handle all this and is all I gain some readability?

Comment: Compiler does not optimize as humans and humans don't optimize as compiler... Not a joke. Wide subject. Do you get the same result sets of all cases with the two methods ? Did you benchmark them ?

Comment: Typo in original code "else" part? `dbl_low = i-1; dbl_low = i;` seems weird here

Comment: Let's say `p_lower = 0.1` and `p_upper = 0.2`, your first code will return `0.0`, your second code will return `f(0.1, 0.2)`. Does this seem equivalent to you?

Comment: If i==low && i==high, doesn't do what you think it does

Comment: how can i==low ever be true when your 3rd statement in the for loop is ++i rather than i++?

Comment: @LarryBud it doesn't really change a thing as this statement is executed at the end of the loop

Comment: yeah, I guess that's true in a loop. I'm so used to seeing i++ that thought it might increment before the loop started

Comment: That got me puzzled the first time as well, I don't really know why, but it seems like there are two schools, like for `{` at the end or on a new line

Comment: (Also returns different results if `p_lower > p_higher`.) Whether the compiler optimizes the first version to the second is dependent upon the compiler. You can use ildasm to see what optimizations are performed.

Comment: I'm working on benchmarking it, after making sure they are equivalent.

@HansKeﬆing As i always starts at i==low and after that is never equal again, this can only mean that low == high (the ceilingsof the original boundaries are equal).

Initially I mistakenly thought that made the last if statement redundant, but that one tests the equality of the original doubles. 

So I had to add two tests for that to the code to make the two equivalent. These tests are outside the loop, as the loop is guaranteed to not have an interval of 0 length.

Comment: Loop-unrolling by the JIT compiler will presumably sort this out. Need to examine assmbler to be sure.

Comment: Tell me again why you'd rather keep `double`s and play with differences, `Math.Abs` and comparisons with `0.00001` than parse to `int` and do equality check?

Comment: @rafalon the function f() in the actual code expects doubles, therefore I used doubles. I find the code more readable without the casts as well. 

I don't actually know the cost of 'converting to int and checking equality' vs 'double substraction and comparing to an epsilon'. Although this does seem like something a compiler could handle.

Comment: I checked; there is no execution time difference between casting to int or what I'm doing now. So I'll stick with doubles.

Comment: I think that if you want to improve your code a tiny bit, you can get rid of your `Math.Abs` (as you already check for `p_upper < p_lower`)

Answer (score 3):

I changed your second function a bit to improve readability:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {

        Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
        const int COUNT = 10000000;

        double[] lowers = new double[COUNT];
        double[] uppers = new double[COUNT];
        double[] result = new double[COUNT];
        double[] result2 = new double[COUNT];

        Random random = new Random();

        for (int i = 0; i < COUNT; i++)
        {
            lowers[i] = Math.Round(random.NextDouble() * 60.0, 2);
            uppers[i] = lowers[i] + Math.Round(random.NextDouble() * 40.0,2);
        }

        sw.Start();
        for (int i = 0; i < COUNT; i++)
        {
            result[i] = SomeFunction(lowers[i], uppers[i]);
        }
        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("Elapsed Time for SomeFunction is {0} ms", sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);

        sw.Reset();
        sw.Start();
        for (int i = 0; i < COUNT; i++)
        {
            result2[i] = SomeFunction2(lowers[i], uppers[i]);
        }
        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("Elapsed Time for SomeFunction2 is {0} ms", sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);

        for (int i = 0; i < COUNT; i++)
        {
            if (result[i] != result2[i])
            {
                Console.WriteLine("i: {0}",i);
            }
        }
    }
    
    public static double SomeFunction(double p_lower, double p_upper) {
        double result = 0.0;
        int low = (int)Math.Ceiling(p_lower);
        int high = (int)Math.Ceiling(p_upper);

        for(int i = low; i <= high; ++i){
            double dbl_low;
            double dbl_high;
      
            if (i == low && i == high) {
                dbl_low = p_lower;
                dbl_high = p_upper;
            } else if (i == low) {
                dbl_low = p_lower;
                dbl_high = i;
            } else if (i == high) {
                dbl_low = i - 1;
                dbl_high = p_upper;
            } else {
                dbl_low = i - 1;
                dbl_high = i;
            }
    
            if (dbl_low != dbl_high) {
                result += f(dbl_low,dbl_high);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
    
    public static double SomeFunction2(double p_lower, double p_upper) {
        double result = 0.0;
        
        if (p_upper <= p_lower) {
            return result;
        }
        
        double low = Math.Ceiling(p_lower);
        double high = Math.Ceiling(p_upper);
   
        /// edge case
        if (high == low) { 
            return f(p_lower, p_upper);
        }
        /// first fraction
        if (low > p_lower) {
            result += f(p_lower, low);
        }

        /// whole intervals
        for (int i = (int)low + 1; i < high; ++i){
            result += f(i-1.0, i);
        }
        /// add last fraction and return
        return result + f(high - 1.0, p_upper);
    }
    
    // Simple function f(a,b) for test purpose
    public static double f(double a, double b)
    {
        return a + b;
    }
}
```

Running this several times gave me:

3680 ms / 1863 ms  -> 49%
2362 ms / 1441 ms  -> 39%
3175 ms / 2030 ms  -> 36%
2956 ms / 1531 ms  -> 48%

So it stays quite close in terms of performance

Comment: You are absolutely correct. Unfortunately I made a mistake trying to make the original code more readable.

I've edited the original code and now both algorithms are the same again.

I also corrected the description of the edge case, it is is the edge case where both the lower and upper limit are between the same integers or in one unit interval.

Comment: @ECo edited to match your updated code, I still could find inputs that behave differently (`0.1, 0.1`)

Comment: No one said this was easy :(

I caught that while you made your edit.

I've since updated the code and ran 10'000'000 calls of each function on an array with random numbers a conservative (low) estimate for our average usecase. With this simple addition function the time difference is ~1950ms for SomeFunction and ~1160ms for Somefunction2. A 40% reduction in execution time by simply moving conditionals out of the loop.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is that the latest MS c# compiler does not optimize this code fully.

I added large arrays of random numbers to Rafalon's program as a crude benchmark.
With this simple addition function the time difference is ~1950ms for SomeFunction and ~1160ms for Somefunction2. A 40% reduction in execution time by simply moving conditionals out of the loop.

Thanks to the people pointing out the error in transcribing the original functions and pointing out there were errors/I had misunderstood part of the original function I managed to get a new function that passes all our unit tests.

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {

        Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
        const int COUNT = 10000000;

        double[] lowers = new double[COUNT];
        double[] uppers = new double[COUNT];
        double[] result = new double[COUNT];
        double[] result2 = new double[COUNT];

        double sumerror = 0.0;
        Random random = new Random();

        for (int i = 0; i < COUNT; i++)
        {
            lowers[i] = Math.Round(random.NextDouble() * 60.0, 2);
            uppers[i] = lowers[i] + Math.Round(random.NextDouble() * 40.0,2);
        }

        sw.Start();
        for (int i = 0; i < COUNT; i++)
        {
            result[i] = SomeFunction(lowers[i], uppers[i]);
        }
        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("Elapsed Time for SomeFunction is {0} ms", sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);

        sw.Reset();
        sw.Start();
        for (int i = 0; i < COUNT; i++)
        {
            result2[i] = SomeFunction2(lowers[i], uppers[i]);
        }
        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("Elapsed Time for SomeFunction2 is {0} ms", sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);

        for (int i = 0; i < COUNT; i++)
        {
            sumerror += (result[i] - result2[i]);
            if (Math.Abs(result[i] - result2[i])> 0.0001)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("i: {0}",i);
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine(sumerror); // should be zero, and we now use the results so no optimizing everything away.
    }
    
    public static double SomeFunction(double p_lower, double p_upper) {
        double result = 0.0;
        int low = (int)Math.Ceiling(p_lower);
        int high = (int)Math.Ceiling(p_upper);

        for(int i = low; i <= high; ++i){
            double dbl_low;
            double dbl_high;
      
            if (i == low && i == high) {
                dbl_low = p_lower;
                dbl_high = p_upper;
            } else if (i == low) {
                dbl_low = p_lower;
                dbl_high = i;
            } else if (i == high) {
                dbl_low = i - 1;
                dbl_high = p_upper;
            } else {
                dbl_low = i - 1;
                dbl_high = i;
            }
    
            if (dbl_low != dbl_high) {
                result += f(dbl_low,dbl_high);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
    
    public static double SomeFunction2(double p_lower, double p_upper) {
        double result = 0.0;
        double low = Math.Ceiling(p_lower);
        double high = Math.Ceiling(p_upper);
   
        
        /// edge case
        if (Math.Abs(high - low) < 0.00001) { 
            return Math.Abs(p_upper-p_lower)< 0.00001? 0.0 : f(p_lower, p_upper);
        }
        /// first fraction
        result += Math.Abs(low - p_lower)< 0.00001? 0.0 : f(p_lower, low);

        /// whole intervals
        for( int i = (int)low + 1; i < high; ++i){
            result += f(i-1.0, i);
        }
        /// add last fraction and return
        return result + f(high - 1.0, p_upper);
    }
    
    // Simple function f(a,b) for test purpose
    public static double f(double a, double b)
    {
        return a + b;
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that your current test does not test the cases where `p_upper <= p_lower` (as you store `uppers[i] = lowers[i] + something_positive`)

Comment: That's on purpose, as the calling functions in the original source check for this. 

For completeness I just benchmarked with an extra condition on line one of SomeFunction2:
if (p_upper < p_lower) return 0.0;
The result is indistinguishable.